# overlaying plots from different dataframes in ggplot without messing with legend

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, legend

I want to overlay two plots: one is a simple point plot where a variable is used to control the dot size; and another is a simple curve.

Here is a dummy example for the first plot;

```
library(ggplot2)
x <- seq(from = 1, to = 10, by = 1)
df = data.frame(x=x, y=x^2, v=2*x)
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, size = v)) + geom_point() + theme_classic() + scale_size("blabla")
```

[image]

Now lets overlay a curve to this plot with data from another dataframe:

```
df2 = data.frame(x=x, y=x^2-x+2)
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, size = v)) + geom_point() + theme_classic() + scale_size("blabla") + geom_line(data=df2, aes(x, y), color = "blue") + scale_color_discrete(name = "other", labels = c("nanana"))
```

It produces the error:

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'v' not found

The value in v is not used to draw the intended curse, but anyway, I added a dummy v to df2.

```
df2 = data.frame(x=x, y=x^2-x+2, v=replicate(length(x),0))  # add a dummy v
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, size = v)) + geom_point() + theme_classic() + scale_size("blabla") + geom_line(data=df2, aes(x, y), color = "blue") + scale_color_discrete(name = "other", labels = c("nanana"))
```

An the result has a messed legend:

[image]

What is the right way to achieve the desired plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the size aes in the geom_point() call to make it so that you don't need the dummy v in `df2`.

Not sure exactly what you want regarding the legend. If you replace the above, then the blue portion goes away. If you want to have a legend for the line color, then you have to place color inside the geom_line aes call.

```
x <- seq(from = 1, to = 10, by = 1)
df = data.frame(x=x, y=x^2, v=2*x)
df2 = data.frame(x=x, y=x^2-x+2)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point(aes(size = v)) + 
  theme_classic() + 
  scale_size("blabla") + 
  geom_line(data=df2, aes(x, y, color = "blue")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = "blue", labels = "nanana", name = "other")
```

[image]